# Voting on items in a document library?

Tags: document-library, survey

I am trying to set up a voting/survey feature in a document library that could potentially contain 50+ images.

Multiple users in my company will be uploading different types of images, then other users will vote on their favorite. I am trying to find a way of setting up a survey or voting option in the library itself so they can see the image as they are voting. The main idea is to try to keep everything in the same library so everything will be automatically updated if a new image gets uploaded.

Does anyone have any ideas on this subject?

Answer (score 3):

Turn on [Ratings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/enable-users-to-rate-content-HA101791797.aspx).  This will allow users to click 1-5 stars against each image.

Comment: Great idea, but the issue with that is that they will be able to vote 5 stars on multiple images. Thank you very much for the suggestion though.

Comment: True - but does that matter?

Comment: So how about creating a separate list to hold the votes then some jQuery to drive a web part on a view of the image library.  When a user selects an image in the library, the jQuery checks to see if they have already voted - if they have not the offer a VOTE button which adds a row to the vote list.  If they have already voted then either do nothing - or a nicer option would be to give a summary of the results from the vote list.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2013 you could try **[InfoWise Voting Column](https://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/comments.aspx?ArticleId=73)** 
(paid [product in Office Store](https://store.office.com/app.aspx?assetid=WA104325640) for SharePoint):

[image: InfoWise Voting Column screenshot]

Description:

> **Overview**
>
> Add a voting capability to any list or document library. Users will be
>   able to vote directly from any list view, optionally leaving comments
>   and starting discussions.
>
> - Add voting column to any list
> - Vote from any view or display form
> - Single or multiple votes for each user
> - Specify discussions board for leaving comments
> - Link comments to the item/document
> - Show comments on display form of the item using Related list
> - Optionally, prevent owners from voting for their items
> - Sort by voting result
>
> Note: in-app purchase is implemented. **Start the app to sign up for a
>   30-day trial**.